# How to accumulate the SQL Column Data

Tags: sql

I have a problem and i want to know if i can do it in SQL.

```
ID  ACC_NO
----------------
1   2342
2   8938
3   8089

Result 
ID  ACC_NO  ACCUM
---------------------
1   2342    11
2   8938    28
3   8089    25
```

I want accumulate the ACC_NO (2+3+4+2 = 11)

Can i do it? is there any option to accumulate data in SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Any good reasons to not do this in your program ? (There might be ! But if not, I'd go for something that is in your code rather than in the DB)

Comment: A particular dbms or just plain sql?

Comment: yes vache is right,you can do it in better way in your program code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.  Here is a way which assumes that your field ACC_NO is always four digits (or less):

```
SELECT ID
       ,ACC_NO
       ,FirstDigit  = (ACC_NO / 1000)       -- Included these
       ,SecondDigit = (ACC_NO % 1000) / 100 -- so you could
       ,ThirdDigit  = (ACC_NO % 100) / 10   -- see the
       ,FourthDigit = (ACC_NO % 10)         -- breakdown
       ,ACCUM       = (ACC_NO / 1000) + ((ACC_NO % 1000) / 100) + ((ACC_NO % 100) / 10) + (ACC_NO % 10)
  FROM MyTable
```

Note: % is the modulus operator

Answer (score 0):

As Vache has given, you should do sum in your program rather than sql.
Though I am giving you solution expecting your number is of 4 digits.

```
SELECT ID, ACC_NO, ( SUBSTRING(ACC_NO,1,1) +SUBSTRING(ACC_NO,2,1) +SUBSTRING(ACC_NO,3,1) +SUBSTRING(ACC_NO,4,1)) as ACCUM
FROM jj_salary_info
```